# How write a for loop with min/max per group, thencalculate with those values by a groups for all those values in a group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I have a CSV file that has the following columns: UniqueWellIdentifier(UWI); Depth; Porosity(PHI); NeutCount(NEUT).

For each UWI, I need to know what the NEUT max and min is, to determine the slope and intercept for each UWI group. Each UWI will have a slightly different transform to use on the NEUT column. So each well will have a different NEUT max/min, SLOPE, INTERCEPT, and it would use that transform for the whole NEUT column for that specific well, and then move on to the next one.

These are the classic steps I am referencing:

1. SLOPE = (log (PHIHI / PHILO)) / (CPSLO - CPSHI)
2. INTCPT = PHIHI / (10^ (CPSLO * SLOPE))
3. NEUTPOR = INTCPT * 10^ (SLOPE * NEUT)

CPSHI = maximum neutron count(NEUT) value per well (UWI)

CPSLO = minimum neutron count(NEUT) value per well (UWI)

PHIHI = minimum average PHI for whole data set

PHILO = minimum average PHI for whole data set

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
q = pd.read_csv('DataFile.csv')

grouped = q.groupby(['UWI'])
for key_uwi in grouped:
    CPSHI = key_uwi.NEUT.min()
    CPSLO = key_uwi.NEUT.max()
    y = np.array([PHILO, PHIHI])
    y = 10**(y / 10.0)
    x = np.array([CPSHI, CPSHLO], 1)
    key_uwi.loc[q.UWI ==key_uwi] = key_uwi.NEUTPOR = [p[i] for i in key_uwi.NEUT]
    q['NEUTPOR'] = NEUTPOR
```

I get the error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'NEUT'

The big issue is I need a max and min NEUT for each UWI group, and then run the y = mx+b transform through the whole NEUT column for EACH UWI separately.

I don't even know if I'm doing the for loop right, and I'm not sure what to even look up to find what I'm looking for, for additional help. Any push in the right direction would help.

Comment: Your text is very long. Can you remove all the background information and concentrate on the actual problem?

Comment: I'll reword it and see if I can cut it down.

Comment: I cut down the description a lot more, hopefully this is clear enough. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Still far too much. Relevant are the code and the error message only. Missing is the full error traceback and what `q` is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `groupby().apply()` call since you are running calculations with multiple aggregates. Below may need testing on sample data:

```
PHIHI = q.groupby(['UWI'])['XPHI'].max().mean() 
PHILO = q.groupby(['UWI'])['XPHI'].min().mean()

def calc_np(grp):
   PHI_Maxes = grp['XPHI'].max() 
   PHI_Mins = grp['XPHI'].min() 
   CPSHI = grp['NEUT'].min() 
   CPSLO = grp['NEUT'].max()

   SLOPE = (np.log(PHIHI / PHILO)) / (CPSLO - CPSHI)
   INTCPT = PHIHI / (10**(CPSLO * SLOPE))
   NEUTPOR = INTCPT * 10**(SLOPE * grp['NEUT'])

   return pd.Series(NEUTPOR)

# CALCULATE NEW COLUMN ZBY GROUP
q['NEUTPOR'] = q.groupby(['UWI']).transform(calc_np)
```